# Realm.io Todo app crashing and not persisting user credentials

Tags: realm

Loaded project https://github.com/realm/my-first-realm-app in Visual Studio (C#), and running into problems. First, changed GetInstanceAsync to GetInstance to fix crash on init. Second, user is not persisted as login screen keeps asking for credentials, even though user as been confirmed via email. Keep in mind that I haven't made any changes to example other than switching to GetInstance method, and replacing AuthUrl with my realm address in the Constant file.
How do I make this work? Thank you